# Unable to connect to remote MySQL database in Node.js application (DOCKER)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, docker

I have `NODE.JS` application which works with remote `MySQL` database. In my local computer (windows 10) application successfully connected to remote `MySQL` database. I use [sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/) library for this task. MySQL database has 40 maximum connection pool for each user. When I run this application in `Docker` which is in `CentOS` server I notice error. Application raise error when try to connect to remote MySQL database in Docker container. What can be the reason of this problem for your opinion? How I can fix this problem?

**ERROR**:

```
Unable to connect to remote MySQL database: { SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:149:19)
    at tryCatcher (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:173:17)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:324:15)
       at processTimers (timers.js:268:5)
     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     fatal: true },
  original:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:173:17)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:324:15)
       at processTimers (timers.js:268:5)
     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     fatal: true } }
```

**JS**:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// "max_user_connections" resource for "db_user" user is "40".
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'db_user', 'db_password', {
    host: 'HOST',
    port: '3306',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
        max: 15,
        min: 5,
        idle: 20000,
        evict: 15000,
        acquire: 30000
    }
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection to remote MySQL database has been established successfully.');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to remote MySQL database:', err);
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**Dependencies**:

```
"sequelize": "^4.42.0",
"mysql2": "^1.6.4"
```

Comment: That mySql server is located where? If it is on the same server and database is also run in the container you need to be sure that both are visible to each other. Can you show Dockerfile + compose file if you have it?

Comment: `MySQL` database is located in remote server. In other words `MySQL` database and Docker container of `Node.js` application are in different servers.

Comment: In fact, the application worked on Docker a few days ago without problems. The problem arose yesterday. Is it possible that each SQL query created the connection and  sequelize library don't close it automatically?

Comment: When I try to ping host where located MySQL database from the server where localed Docker it show me such strange message: `From 172.23.0.1 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You are pinging 172.23.0.1? Are you 100% sure that IP address is public address of that server? I am not guru in networking, but that doesn't sound like a public IP address to me.

Comment: And have you checked firewall? Do you use ufw or something else? Try to allow MySQL port on the server where it is located.

Comment: I don't pint `172.23.0.1`. This ip address of server where located Docker. I ping host where located remote MySQL database. I don't know about firewall. How to check if there is a firewall on the server?